# ALTER DATABASE on a current db without explicit db name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to be able to write sql query that changes the database to which I am currently logged in.

Example:

```
$ psql my_db
psql(9.1.1)
my_db=> ALTER DATABASE my_db SET some_variable = '0';
                       ^^^^^
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying the database name in this query?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're on 9.1 you can use:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   execute 'alter database '||current_database()||' set some_var = ''0''';
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are executing the script in `psql` you can use the substitution mechanism of `psql`:

```
alter database :DBNAME SET ...
```

The documentation is here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES

Answer (score 3):

Combining a few things together, including previous answers and the "\gset" technique mentioned in http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/postgresql-psql-variable-from-query.html, and the most streamlined way is:

```
-- note no semicolon after \gset:
select current_database() \gset
alter database :current_database set some_var = '0';
```