# How do I append a schema to the postgresql database default search_path?

Tags: postgresql

I already know how to set the search_path per database or user (alter database set search_path to schema1, schema2, ...).

What I would like to do is append a schema to the default search path. I know I can get the current search path (show search_path) but this could have been altered during the session.

The purpose is something like:

```
create schema postgis;
set search_path to postgis;
create extension postgis;
alter database the_db set search_path to <the current default>, postgis;
```

I can do this manually but I want to add this to a function that could be called after the user altered the session search path.

Comment: How did you append?

Comment: Did you find a way to append?

Answer (score 2):

This updates `search_path` for current session & also future sessions. base on [these](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56023) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331761/1696720) posts

```
    DO $$
    BEGIN
      execute 'alter database '||current_database()||' set search_path to '||current_setting('search_path')||',extensions';
      execute 'set search_path to '||current_setting('search_path')||',extensions';
    END
    $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it.

For my purposes I can just do

```
set search_path to default;
```

before appending.